# Sound manipulation reverse/playing recorded sound backwards on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio, audio-recording

I try to get my head around how to deal with some challenging requirements for my iPhone app.

These are the requirements:

2. Record sound (voice of a person)
3. High quality 44100Mhz - 32 bit
4. Slow down playback (without pitching voice to high or to low!). however we would like to know how to do pitching/alter voice high and low as well.
5. Convert/process the voice backwards (reverse) and save/store it on the mobile device (OpenAL?)
6. Mark and cut/delete parts out off a recorded or reversed file
7. Convert file to MP3 or Wave for later amendments

Answer (score 0):

What is the question?

I would consider coverting and storing the raw sound data to a float array. Forwards vs backwards is just a matter of how you iterate through the array. I think slowing down, without changing pitch, requires dividing the file up into "granules" that get replayed.

If you want to edit the sounds, you are talking about building a lot of GUI. Something like Audacity would be a good reference.

I'm not sure how to read 32-bit encoded wav files. Maybe the Java implementation on the iPhone has this built in? Otherwise you may have to read up on RIFF/WAV headers in order to strip them from the raw data.

If you want to use MP3, I think there's a fellow by the name of Freunhofer that you have to deal with in terms of licensing.

Who came up with the requirements? Voice can be recorded at a lot lower fidelity and still be understandable.